Java 21 different result for DateFormat::format for English and other languages
I am migrating legacy code from Java 17 to 21 and faced interesting problem for returned values from DateFormat::format method for English and German (but it is the same for other non english language as well). The problem occurs for English when in particular time format part AM/PM exists. It is the minimal code to be able reproduce problem.
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static java.text.DateFormat.SHORT;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat endf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        endf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

        DateFormat gedf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(SHORT, Locale.GERMAN);
        gedf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

        var enDate = endf.format(new Date(1727163143068L));
        var geDate = gedf.format(new Date(1727163143068L));

        assert(enDate.equals("8:32 AM"));
        assert(geDate.equals("09:32"));

        System.out.println(enDate); // prints: 8:32 AM 
        System.out.println(geDate); // prints: 09:32
    }
}

Assertion for enDate.equals("8:32 AM") fails because the string is represented as not LATIN-1 (code=1) and each character is represented by two bytes. I have plenty of tests in project where compares with expected hardcoded time value. Is there any trick to compare those strings as it is displayed (this is the purpose of test) but not how they organised inside String object?


The reason it's not matching as equal is not (directly) related to the coder: the coder is just an internal detail that will never visible influence the behaviour of the String instance. The coder is different, because the string seems to be using U+202F (Narrow Non-break Space) to separate the time and the period indicator. That seems to be the typographically correct way, but probably not what you expected. So to summarize: equals return false because the strings aren't equal. It's not because the coder is different. The Locale used for the formatting apparently changed with 21.

Shouldn't you be using class DateTimeFormatter rather than class DateFormat?

@Abra That wouldn't have made a difference. The switch from a space to Narrow Non-break Space applies to all of them, IIRC.

While Mark Rotteveel is correct, Abra is certainly correct too: The clear recommendation is to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API for all of your date and time work. DateFormat, Date and TimeZone all had bad design problems and have been outdated for 10 years. The question asked remains valid.
